# Warning: data is not aligned! This can lead to a speedloss

Tags: objective-c, streaming, video-streaming, rtsp

i look this [project](https://github.com/durfu/DFURTSPPlayer) and its working for one video. I try to have more then one, so i tried with 2 videos. Here is how i do : `

```
-(void)displayNextFrame:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    NSTimeInterval startTime = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];

    if (![video2 stepFrame]) {
        [timer invalidate];
        [video2 closeAudio];
        return;
    }

    if (![video stepFrame]) {
        [timer invalidate];
        [video closeAudio];
        return;
    }

    imageView.image = video.currentImage;
    imageView2.image = video2.currentImage;


    float frameTime = 1.0/([NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]-startTime);
    if (lastFrameTime<0) {
        lastFrameTime = frameTime;
    } else {
        lastFrameTime = LERP(frameTime, lastFrameTime, 0.8);
    }
    [label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f",lastFrameTime]];

}`
```

I little bit change the first project (delete the play button and videos are played after lauching the application). Here is how i start videos :

```
-(void)playVideo{
    lastFrameTime = -1;

    // seek to 0.0 seconds
    [video seekTime:0.0];

    [video2 seekTime:0.0];

    [_nextFrameTimer invalidate];
    self.nextFrameTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0/30
                                                           target:self
                                                         selector:@selector(displayNextFrame:)
                                                         userInfo:nil
                                                          repeats:YES];
}



  - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    [imageView2 setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    [self playVideo];


}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    if ((self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil])) {
        //http://www.wowza.com/_h264/BigBuckBunny_115k.mov
        //rtsp://media1.law.harvard.edu/Media/policy_a/2012/02/02_unger.mov
        //rtsp://streaming.parliament.act.gov.au/medium

        //rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov
        //rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/test
        //rtsp://mm2.pcslab.com/mm/7h800.mp4


        //video 1
        video = [[RTSPPlayer alloc] initWithVideo:@"rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov" usesTcp:NO];
        video.outputWidth = 426;
        video.outputHeight = 320;

        NSLog(@"video duration: %f",video.duration);
        NSLog(@"video size: %d x %d", video.sourceWidth, video.sourceHeight);

        //video 2
        video2 = [[RTSPPlayer alloc] initWithVideo:@"rtsp://mm2.pcslab.com/mm/7h800.mp4" usesTcp:NO];
        video2.outputWidth = 426;
        video2.outputHeight = 320;

        NSLog(@"video 2 duration: %f",video2.duration);
        NSLog(@"video 2 size: %d x %d", video2.sourceWidth, video2.sourceHeight);
    }

    return self;
}
```

But when i build this code,there is no error, the 2 videos are displayed and then its crashing with the warning : data is not aligned! This can lead to a speedloss. There is something wrong? i dont understand why it doesnt work.. Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you have a delay between A/V, crashing encoder. As this question show same error: http://superuser.com/questions/728795/new-ffmpeg-swscaler-0xa314080-warning-data-is-not-aligned-this-can-lead/799987

Comment: i didn't understand the last answer of this post, but i saw that his problem is about Ubuntu issue